# Invalid callback id received by sendPluginResult - Cordova Plugin iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to implement cordova plugin for ARKit in my ionic app which measures distance between two points. I am able to successfully take the measurements but I am not able to get the measured data back as a result in my ionic app. Below is how my code looks like:

**MeasurePlugin+ViewControllerDelegate.swift**

```
extension MeasurePlugin: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func allowMultiple() -> Bool {
        return allowMultiplePoints ?? false;
    }

    //Dismiss View
    func closeView() {
        let data = myViewController.getMeasures();
        var result: CDVPluginResult
        if (!allowMultiple() && data.count > 0) {
            result = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAs: data[0])
        } else {
            result = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAs: data)
        }
        NSLog(result.message as! String); //getting measured value here
        myViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.myViewController = nil

        result.setKeepCallbackAs(true)
        commandDelegate!.send(result, callbackId: finishListenerCallbackId)
    }

    @objc func setFinishListener(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        finishListenerCallbackId = command.callbackId
    }
}
```

**My www/cordova-plugin-measure.js file looks like:**

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
var pluginName = 'MeasurePlugin';

/**
 * Callback when the view is dismissed
 */
exports.onFinish = function (success = function(){
    console.log("OnFinish Success");
}, error = function(){}) {
    exec(success, error, pluginName, 'setFinishListener');
};
```

So when i try to dismiss the view by calling closeView() function, I am getting error in xcode as "Invalid callback id received by sendPluginResult". Please note, I do get my measure value inside result (notice NSLog(result.message as! String); code) but it is not sending that value back to my ionic component. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?